# Security sandbox violation in Windows Server 2008

Tags: flash, apache-flex, cross-domain, windows-server-2008, httprequest

I am experiencing a Security violation error when I make HTTP Requests to my webserver.

```
Error #2044: Unhandled securityError:. text=Error #2170: Security sandbox violation:
```

I have the following crossdomain file in the root of my server, and I am using the same configuration in a server I host in my machine. However, the webserver I am unable to connect is a Windows Server 2008 R2

This is my crossdomain.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*"  secure="false"/>
    <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" secure="false" /> 
</cross-domain-policy>
```

And this is my .as file

```
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://123.456.789.123:8000/crossdomain.xml");
Security.allowDomain("*");

(...)

var enc:Base64Encoder = new Base64Encoder();    
enc.encodeBytes(myBytes);
var base64str:String = enc.toString();

var url_request:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
url_request.url = "http://123.456.789.123:8000/app/res/func";
url_request.contentType = "text/plain";
url_request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;

var requestVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
requestVars.base64 = base64str;
url_request.data = requestVars;
url_request.requestHeaders.push(
new URLRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache'));

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;//BINARY;
```

I have virtually tried every possible configuration of crossdomain properties but nothign seems to work. What makes it so strange is that the same configuration works for another server. Is there any Windows Server 2008 specificity that I have overlooked? Any tips?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the port 8000 is open for communication?

Comment: Yes, I can make HTTP Requests from other platforms.

Comment: why not put the crossdomain in the root of the app, so you can load the security file from http://123.456.789.123:8000/app/crossdomain.xml